# Query that will pull the maximum value of a column without showing that column

Tags: sql-server, r

Lets say I have a table like this:

```
|  FileName | Category | Value | Number |
|:---------:|:--------:|:-----:|:------:|
| TAG File1 | First    |    10 |      1 |
| TAG File1 | Second   |     8 |      1 |
| TAG File1 | Third    |     4 |      1 |
| TAG File2 | First    |    13 |      1 |
| TAG File2 | Second   |     5 |      1 |
| TAG File2 | Third    |     6 |      1 |
| TAG File1 | First    |    11 |      2 |
| TAG File1 | Second   |     7 |      2 |
| TAG File1 | Third    |     5 |      2 |
| TAG File2 | First    |    14 |      2 |
| TAG File2 | Second   |     6 |      2 |
| TAG File2 | Third    |     5 |      2 |
| TAG File1 | First    |    10 |      3 |
| TAG File1 | Second   |     6 |      3 |
| TAG File1 | Third    |     5 |      3 |
| TAG File2 | First    |    12 |      3 |
| TAG File2 | Second   |     7 |      3 |
| TAG File2 | Third    |     4 |      3 |
```

I want to have a query that will yield this from the data:

```
|  FileName | Category | Value | Number |
|:---------:|:--------:|:-----:|:------:|
| TAG File1 | First    |    10 |      3 |
| TAG File1 | Second   |     6 |      3 |
| TAG File1 | Third    |     5 |      3 |
| TAG File2 | First    |    12 |      3 |
| TAG File2 | Second   |     7 |      3 |
| TAG File2 | Third    |     4 |      3 |
```

I could easily do this by

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Number = 3;
```

But lets say that this table is continually recording data and the `Number` column is keeping track of each time data is collected again. But I want to be able to pull data with one query that will always give me the "most recent" number. In other words, the maximum value in the `Number` column. However, I also don't want the number column to actually show up in the results. So it would look like this:

```
|  FileName | Category | Value |
|:---------:|:--------:|:-----:|
| TAG File1 | First    |    10 |
| TAG File1 | Second   |     6 |
| TAG File1 | Third    |     5 |
| TAG File2 | First    |    12 |
| TAG File2 | Second   |     7 |
| TAG File2 | Third    |     4 |
```

In my head I could see the query reading like this:

```
SELECT FileName, Category, Value
FROM Table
WHERE Number = "Maximum";
```

But of course this wouldn't work at all...

Is this possible?

**EDIT**: I wrote this question without addressing probably the biggest issue. I'm writing these queries in R using `sqlQuery` function which I've never been able to get sub-queries to work. In other words, I can't just write:

```
SELECT FileName, Category, Value
FROM Table
WHERE (select Max(Number) from Table);
```

Comment: what is preventing you to write a simple `sub-query`? `WHERE Number = SELECT MAX(Number) FROM Table`

Comment: @techspider Ah that's actually a good question that I should have addressed in the original answer. I didn't think about that because I've gotten used to not being able to do subqueries in this area. See the edit I'm going to make.

Comment: I'm not sure which SQL Server version are you on as per your tags!!I hope `CTE` works for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CTE` to make it work.  Please see below code:

```
;WITH TempHolder AS
(
    SELECT MAX(Number) MaxNumber FROM Table
)
SELECT FileName, Category, Value FROM Table t1
JOIN TempHolder th ON t1.Number = th.MaxNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
with most_recent as ( 
  SELECT t.FileName, t.Category, MAX(t.Number) as Number
  FROM Table t
  GROUP BY t.FileName, t.Category
)

select t.FileName, t.Category, t.value
  FROM Table t
  INNER JOIN most_recent mr
  ON (mr.FileName = t.FileName and mr.Category = t.Category and mr.Number = t.Number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
    FileName, 
    Category, 
    Value
FROM
    Table
ORDER BY
    Number DESC
```